# Replacement for DialogCallbackHandler in Java 9

Tags: java, java-11, pkcs#11

I'm using SunPKCS11 with NSS to obtain a client certificate from a smart card. For obtaining the PIN I use DialogCallbackHandler. These are both specified in the java.security file.

I need a way to prompt the user for their PIN. It **cannot** be stored, read from a file, passed as a command-line argument, etc.

Note that I have no control over the code used for authentication. It's using the standard Java security implementation.

I've looked at all of the Java 11 implementations of CallbackHandler. None of them appear to do what I want.

Here are the relevant lines from *java.security* which work in Java 8 but not in Java 9:

```
security.provider.10=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /etc/pkcs11.cfg
auth.login.defaultCallbackHandler=com.sun.security.auth.callback.DialogCallbackHandler
```

When client certificate authentication is requested, the user should be prompted for their PIN like they were with **DialogCallbackHandler**.

1. Is there a drop-in replacement for **DialogCallbackHandler**?
2. If the answer to #1 is **no**, Java 8 had the **endorsed** directory where you could drop in extra JARs. Is there a similar facility in Java 9+? Can I simply create a JAR with DialogCallbackHandler and add it somewhere so that it takes effect system-wide?

Comment: What’s your question? How to implement a `CallbackHandler` with a dialog or how to add it to the class path?

Comment: I've updated my question to explicitly state what I'm trying to do at the very end.

Comment: The callback handler that you specify in the configuration doesn't have built-in into the JDK. So yes, you could do the equivalent of DialogCallbackHandler and deploy the class file in a JAR file on the class path.

Comment: OK, how do I do that system-wide without having to manually specify, say, the class path used by Eclipse?